# Can't Define user function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't define any user defined function in python

Indentation and spelling is all correct but i don't know what is happening exactly

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytjhl.jpg)

Refrence code --

```python
def display_board(board):
    
    print( board[7],"|", board[8],"|", board[9] )
    print("--|---|--")
    print( board[4],"|", board[5],"|", board[6] )
    print("--|---|--")
    print( board[1],"|", board[2], "|",board[3] )

#********************************************************#

#test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
#display_board(xyz)

#********************************************************#

def player_input():
   
    while True:
        player_1 = input("Please select character ('X' or 'O'): ").upper()
        if player_1 == "X" or player_1 == "O" :
            break
        elif player_1 != "X" or player_1 != "O" :
            print("Wrong character!!!", end=" ") 
                   
    if player_1 == "X":
        return print("X", "O")
    else:
        return print("O", "X")

#************************************************************************************#    
#player_input()
#************************************************************************************#

def place_marker(board, player_1, position):
    board[position] = player_1


place_marker(test_board,'$',8)
display_board(test_board)
```

```
PS C:\Users\lohar> & C:/Users/lohar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "d:/Vs code/Programs/Tic_Tac_Toe.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Vs code\Programs\Tic_Tac_Toe.py", line 14, in <module>
    display_board(xyz)
NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
PS C:\Users\lohar> & C:/Users/lohar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "d:/Vs code/Programs/Tic_Tac_Toe.py"
Please select character ('X' or 'O'): o
O X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Vs code\Programs\Tic_Tac_Toe.py", line 40, in <module>
    place_marker(test_boar,'$',8)
NameError: name 'test_boar' is not defined
PS C:\Users\lohar>
```

Comment: What do you expect `display_board(xyz)` to do? What is `xyz`?

Comment: the code in the picture is not the same as the code you posted

Comment: Also, there seems to be a typo ‘test_boar’ vs the ‘test_board’ list defined above

Comment: that is called debugging and the first part is reading the error message, if that is not clear strip your program and find out which part is generating the error, if you have a 5000+ line source code we will not do it for you, `Indentation and spelling is all correct` most likely not otherwise you would not have an error

Answer (score 0):

Do this you will get your output

```
def display_board(board):
    
    print( board[7],"|", board[8],"|", board[9] )
    print("--|---|--")
    print( board[4],"|", board[5],"|", board[6] )
    print("--|---|--")
    print( board[1],"|", board[2], "|",board[3] )
  
test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']  
display_board(test_board)
```

Note: Only pass which is called. EX. here test_board is defined so you have to pass test_board

Comment: I tried that but no help and not only this but my all function having same issue

Comment: Just go through this link and copy paste this code, you will get correct output   https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/